# What should be the partition scheme for Ubuntu 18.04 500 GB HDD (no SSD, no dual boot)?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, hard-drive, java

I have a 500 GB HDD.
When I was using Windows, I gave 150 GB to C drive (just to be on the safe side) and 315 GB to D drive.

I used C drive just for installing software. I stored my personal files and projects/programs I created in C and C++ in D drive.

Now I want to learn java and I'm thinking to use Ubuntu.
If I was using windows, I would install the Java related programs in C drive and will save the projects created in D drive.

How should I partition my HDD in Ubuntu?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88537/discussion-on-question-by-shreekar-sharma-what-should-be-the-partition-scheme-fo).

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to your question "What should be the partition scheme for ubuntu 18.04 lts 500gb hdd?" is: how you wish it to be. There is no rules. You should partition according on how *you* want to organize your data.

By default, the installer will establish **one single partition** containing system and user data. For a personal computer (not a server), this is the simplest solution. The drawback is that if you do a clean install in the future, then you also will need to place your data back. This is the simplest configuration, and there is nothing wrong with that.

Some people prefer to have a **separate home partition**. The root partition can then be as small as 15 GB or less. The second partition is then mounted on /home. Thus, all user configuration data *and* user data will be on the other partition. The convenience here is that your user data can remain in case you do a fresh reinstall in the future.

None of these scenarioś eliminates the need to having good backups of your personal data on removable drives or media.

Comment: Hello I am a developer thus intend to install lot of software in the future. So would 15Gb be sufficient for the root? And what is an ideal scheme, I am also using Windows alongside and have a total disk of 500gb.

Comment: IF you plan to install a lot of software, 20 or even 25 Gb may be safer. The ideal scheme is the scheme that works best for you.